# How to find textbox1.text in objdatatable?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want find `textbox1.text` in `objdatatable.`

```
objdataadapter.Fill(objdatatable);

foreach (DataRow dt in objdatatable.Rows)
{
    if (dt.Equals(txtaddgroup.Text)))
}
```

how use `dt.Equals(txtaddgroup.Text)` correctly ?

Comment: what is the exact problem?

Comment: provide error message also with your question

Comment: how use dt.Equals(txtaddgroup.Text) correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `row` in dt you probably need to use some column name to compare it with text of `txtaddgroup`

```
foreach (DataRow dt in objdatatable.Rows)
{
     if (dt["ColumnName"].ToString() == txtaddgroup.Text)
     {
        //You code
     }
}
```

Comment: ) in end of if (dt["ColumnName"].ToString() == txtaddgroup.Text)) should remove.

Answer (score 0):

you are just missing the column name:

```
foreach (DataRow dt in objdatatable.Rows)
{
    if (dt["ColumnName"].Equals(txtaddgroup.Text))
    {
    }
}
```

you can use `Column Name` as well as `Column Index`

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to `convert` it to a `string`, it is an `object`. So you will only need to `cast` it to a `string` using: `(string)`

```
foreach (DataRow dt in objdatatable.Rows)
{
     if ((string)dt["ColumnName"] == txtaddgroup.Text)
     {
        //You code
     }
}
```